# php producing 'no such timezone' error on new setup

Tags: php, symfony, installation, xampp

While running symfony2 application (which is already running commercially) on my localhost XAMPP server I am receiving the following error:

`Warning: IntlDateFormatter::setTimeZone(): datefmt_set_timezone: no such time zone: '1024' in C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\SBSonline\sbsonline-v2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType.php line 267`

my php.ini file sets the timezone as it should:

`date.timezone= "Europe/London"`

from the stack it looks like the error is coming from the formBuilder but as said the application is working on the main server.

Ive tried replacing the php_intl.dll file just in case but its made no difference.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which timezone shows phpinfo()?

Comment: Europe/London.  worked out a fix, but its a bit hacky. Ill post it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after no luck I found that if you edit the vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType.php directly you can trick it

change the default code from:

```
    if (version_compare(\PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0-dev', '>=')) {
        $formatter->setTimeZone(\DateTimeZone::UTC);
    } else {
        $formatter->setTimeZoneId(\DateTimeZone::UTC);
    }
```

to:

```
    if (version_compare(\PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0-dev', '>=')) {
        $formatter->setTimeZone('UTC');
    } else {
        $formatter->setTimeZoneId(\DateTimeZone::UTC);
    }
```

we're running symfony 2.1/php 5.5.15, so I dont know if its a compatibility issue between the 2 or not.